# Shell Restore Using Tar

Tags: shell

I have been trying to create a shell script that backs up and restores a certain directory. The code will backup the directory but when it comes to restoring I cant get it to work.

**Code now works added line below to restore function**

```
tar xvpfz $DESTIN/$BACKUP -C /
```

**Globals**

```
CREATE="/dev /proc /sys /temp /run /mnt /media "
DESTIN="/Users/Rory/test/"
BACKUP="backup2.tgz"
```

**Backup Code**

```
elif [ "$opt" = "BACKUP" ]; then
echo "BACKING UP FILES..."
sleep 2
tar cvpfz $DESTIN/backup.`date +%d%m%y_%k:%M`.tgz $ROOT $ROOT_EXCLUDE_DIRS
echo "BACKUP COMPLETE"
sleep 2
exit
```

**Restore Code**

```
elif [ "$opt" = "RESTORE" ]; then
echo "RESTOTING FILES..."
sleep 2
tar xvpfz $DESTIN/$BACKUP -C /
sleep 2
echo "RESTORE COMPLETE..."
if [[ -e "/proc" ]]; then
        echo "$CREATE_DIRS already exists! "
else
        mkdir $CREATE
        echo "$CREATE are created! "
fi
exit
```

**Error**

```
tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open '-C'
```

Comment: Souds like `$BACKUP` is an empty string in the "Restore Code"...

Comment: But I have set '$BACKUP' as 'backup2.tgz' at the top of the code?

Comment: Sure, looks like. But the error message hints that "-C" is the first argument, does it not?

Comment: Writing Bash is quite knew to me so Im still learning, do you know how I can go about fixing this, have been looking around the internet but cant seem to find help

Comment: Try to dump it to see what you have got: `echo tar xvpfz $BACKUP -C /` or similar...

Comment: The dump gave back the file name of the backup `backup2.tgz` which is what I was expecting, do you know any other reason that would cause the error?

Comment: Sorry, looks fine to me otherwise...

Comment: You might want to check your date format you're using as part of your backup tarball name: %k will generate a space-padded hour like " 9:15" -- use %H:%M to get the zero-padding "09:15".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your restore code code you need to remove the space between `$DESTIN` and `$BACKUP`

code should be

```
tar xvpfz $DESTIN/$BACKUP -C /
```